# How to find the number of elements in a specific set given the number of elements of an intersection of 2 sets

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $A_1, A_2, A_3$ form a partition of the universal set $S$. Let $B$ be an arbitrary set. Assume that we know

$|B\cap A_1|=10$,

$|B\cap A_2|=20$,

$|B\cap A_3|=15$.

Find $|B|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A_1, A_2, A_3$ is a partition, they are disjoint and their union is the universal set.

Hence $$\left|B\right|=\left|B \cap S\right|=\left|B \cap \bigcup A_i \right| =\left|\bigsqcup (B \cap A_i )\right|=\sum_{i=1}^3\left|B \cap A_i\right|=10+20+15$$

Comment: I see it now. Thank you very much.